# Changing the website URL to the root folder

Tags: urls, site-url

Right now on my root folder, I have an "Under construction" page. So just an index.html, and a style. Then I have a test folder with Wordpress in it, so my website URL is root/test/wordpress. I want to "upload" the website to the root folder so I see the site instead of the under construction page. I have tried changing the website URL in the Wordpress dashboard but that does not work. I have also tried adding the new address in the wp-config file but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want to transfer the site from www.example.com/test/wordpress to the www.example.com.

To do so you have to have access to **FTP** or **CPANEL/PLESK** to actually cut files from the old location to the new. When you finished that you can use this tool to make the **correct changes** to the database( including the serialized part).

Then remove the **index.html** file and you would be good to go.

This is the tools I used [search-and-replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "cut files from the old location to the new". Shouldn't it work by changing the Website URL in the Dashboard?

Comment: Changing the URL from the dashboard will not change the actual URL PATH the users has to go. So to make this at the root of your domain like the under construction page you have to move the content of the folder of the test/wordpress to the root folder so the root folder now has the wp-content folder and the others. Hope this clear the things up.

Comment: I have done that and now I get an http error 500.

Comment: Use the tool to make the changes from the Database. Also check if you have make any change to the htaccess including the url rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry actually I'd like to give comment rather create answer but my reputation not enough. You can refer to this document:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

> - The "Site Address (URL)" setting is the address you want people to    type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.
> - The "WordPress    Address (URL)" setting is the address where your WordPress core files    reside.

Dont forget to save your permalink again after create these changed.

Comment: How am I supposed to change the permalinks when i can't access my site anymore? When I follow these steps, adding "update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://oxirealty.com' );" or changing the site url in the wp-config.php file I just can't access my site anymore, there's something else preventing my redirect from working.

Comment: You missed the http:// or https://  

`update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://oxirealty.com'; );`

If you already have to changed without http:// https:// then you must update them through mysql database

Comment: Looking through wp_options table (or if you have set other database prefix its kind of yourprefix_options table )